# Append Date to Filename in Windows Batch File

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file

I have a batch file which backs up my SQL Database and want to append the date to the end of the file created.

> sqlcmd -U sa -P pwd -S SERVER\SQL2012 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO 
>   DISK = N'E:\Databases\MYDB.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME =
>   N'MYDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
>   -d "MYDB"

Currently all my back ups are getting added to the MYDB.bak file but I want to have new file names for each backup with the date e.g. MYDB20141028.bak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option if you want to do the date appending in SQL is to pass multiple commands like this:

> sqlcmd -U sa -P pwd -S SERVER\SQL2012 -Q "DECLARE @dest
>   NVARCHAR(max);SET @dest = N'E:\Databases\MYDB' +
>   CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak';BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO
>   DISK = @dest' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'MYDB-Full Database
>   Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10" -d "MYDB"

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current date by parsing the output of the `date` command.

The following will work if your locale is US English.

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE=%%k%%i%%j
```

It will take the output of `date /t` and re-arrange it.  The delimiters are set to be the forward slash and space.  Then it takes tokens 2,3,4 and outputs them in the order 4,2,3.

So it will take `Mon 10/27/2014` and split it into the tokens:

1. Mon
2. 10
3. 27
4. 2014

And will set the `DATE` variable to `20141027`.

With that you can change our backup command to:

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P pwd -S SERVER\SQL2012 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO DISK = 
N'E:\Databases\MYDB%DATE%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'MYDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP,
NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10" -d "MYDB"
```

Comment: Does the `date` command return date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format?  For example, if the date was `9/1/2014`, would this return `20140901` or `201491`?

Comment: For US English systems it returns mm/dd/yyyy.  However that format is set based on the current locale.  So an UK English the format would be different.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've used the answer provided by jpw as I tried what you mentioned but couldn't fully figure it out. Thanks anways.